# Epigraph and fancyhdr: a patching problem

Tags: fancyhdr, report, epigraphs, xpatch

I would like to add epigraphs on my part pages using `epigraph`, but since I also use `fancyhdr`, I cannot get the proper page style on the part page using the solution given in the package documentation.

Since I use the `report` class, I thought of patching the command `\@part` using the package `xpatch`. All I have to do is to insert a command `\insertepigraph` just before `\@endpart` (with a couple of `\vfill` and `\vskip` to keep the page style sensible). A command called `\partepigraph` redefine the command to include the `\epigraph` command, which is cleared immediatly after  by `\clearpartepigraph` so the command affects only one part page.

This approach works perfectly when manually editing report.cls, but pachting the command with `\xpatchcmd` have no effect, and I do not understand what is wrong with my code (It is the first time I use this command myself).

Could someone help me fixing my code ?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}

\newcommand\insertepigraph{} % Insert an epigraph at the bottom of a part page
\newcommand\clearpartepigraph{\renewcommand\insertepigraph{}} % Clear the part epigraph
\newcommand\partepigraph[2]{\renewcommand{\insertepigraph}{\epigraph{#1}{#2}}} % Define the part epigraph

\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}
{\@endpart}%
{\vfill\insertepigraph\clearpartepigraph\@endpart}%
{\PackageWarning{Patch}{Success}}
{\PackageWarning{Patch}{Failure}}

\xpatchcmd{\@part}
{\markboth{}{}}%
{\markboth{}{}\vskip 0.25\textheight}%
{\PackageWarning{Patch}{Success}}
{\PackageWarning{Patch}{Failure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\partepigraph{\footnotesize La notion de passoire est indépendante de la notion de trou, et réciproquement.\\ \vskip3mm The notion of a colander is independant of the notion of a hole, and reciprocally.}{Rouxel (Les Shadoks)\\ \textit{{\scriptsize mocking the non-intuitive principles of quantum mechanics.}}}

\part{Some part title}

\part{Some other part title}

\part{Again some other part title}

\chapter{Ciel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifpatchable{\@part}{\@endpart}{\typeout{Yes}}{\typeout{Nope!}}` yields: Nope! You can't patch `\@part` this way then. How about `\xpretocmd{\@endpart}` with your code that should be done before `\@endpart` is used?

Comment: `\xpretocmd{\@endpart}{\vfill\insertepigraph\clearpartepigraph}{}{}`works fine, but any idea how to add the `\vskip 0.25\textheight` at the level of `\markboth{}{}` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet! I'll try to understand why the command isn't patchable at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `hyperref` does some changes to the structuring level code such that `\xpatchcmd{\@part}{...}` etc. can't work anymore. Do the change before `hyperref` is used, i.e. load `hyperref` later on.

`hyperref` uses various driver files and some of use `\def\@part`, thereby changing the behaviour (slightly) → `\@endpart` and other code hooks can't be found anymore.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%\tracingpatches


\makeatletter

\tracingpatches
\ifpatchable{\@part}{\addcontentsline}{\typeout{Yes}}{\typeout{Nope!}}
\xpatchcmd{\@part}
{\@endpart}%
{\vfill\insertepigraph\clearpartepigraph\@endpart}%
{\PackageWarning{Patch}{Success}}
{\PackageWarning{Patch}{Failure}}

\xpatchcmd{\@part}
{\markboth{}{}}%
{\markboth{}{}\vskip 0.25\textheight}%
{\PackageWarning{Patch}{Success}}
{\PackageWarning{Patch}{Failure}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}

\newcommand\insertepigraph{} % Insert an epigraph at the bottom of a part page
\newcommand\clearpartepigraph{\renewcommand\insertepigraph{}} % Clear the part epigraph
\newcommand\partepigraph[2]{\renewcommand{\insertepigraph}{\epigraph{#1}{#2}}} % Define the part epigraph


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\partepigraph{\footnotesize La notion de passoire est indépendante de la notion de trou, et réciproquement.\\ \vskip3mm The notion of a colander is independant of the notion of a hole, and reciprocally.}{Rouxel (Les Shadoks)\\ \textit{{\scriptsize mocking the non-intuitive principles of quantum mechanics.}}}

\part{Some part title}

\part{Some other part title}

\part{Again some other part title}

\chapter{Ciel}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple redefinition of `\@endpart`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{}%
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}

\newcommand\insertepigraph{} % Insert an epigraph at the bottom of a part page
\newcommand\clearpartepigraph{\renewcommand\insertepigraph{}} % Clear the part epigraph
\newcommand\partepigraph[2]{\renewcommand{\insertepigraph}{\epigraph{#1}{#2}}} % Define the part epigraph

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \markboth{}{}
    \vspace{0.25\textheight}%
    {\centering
        \interlinepenalty \@M \normalfont
        \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart\par
        \vskip 20\p@ \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@endpart{%
    \vfill\insertepigraph\clearpartepigraph\newpage
    \if@twoside\if@openright\null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \newpage\fi\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{plain}

    \partepigraph{\footnotesize La notion de passoire est indépendante de la notion de trou, et réciproquement.\\ \vskip3mm The notion of a colander is independant of the notion of a hole, and reciprocally.}{Rouxel (Les Shadoks)\\ \textit{{\scriptsize mocking the non-intuitive principles of quantum mechanics.}}}

    \part{Some part title}

    \part{Some other part title}

    \part{Again some other part title}

    \chapter{Ciel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works nice too, but what about the `\vskip 0.25\textheight` at the level of `\markboth{}{}` ?

Comment: Where should the `\vskip` appear? Before or after the epigraph?

Comment: Above the moment when \thepart and \partname are being written.

Comment: see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Always do `\show\command` before trying a patch, so as to ensure that you know what to patch. If you add `\show\@part` before the first `\xpatchcmd`, you'll get the following output in the console (and in the `log` file):

```
> \@part=macro:
->\ifnum \Hy@secnum@part >\c@secnumdepth \phantomsection \fi \H@old@part .
l.23 \show\@part

?
```

It's like an error message, but not a real error because there's no leading `!`.

What does this mean? That `hyperref` already did something on `\@part`: it does the usual `\let\old@part\@part` and `\def\@part{<something>\old@part}` to add some actions before the real command is performed.

The good candidate is `\H@old@part` and, indeed, typing `i\show\H@old@part` at the prompt gives

```
? i\show\H@old@part
> \H@old@part=macro:
[#1]#2->\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax \refstepcounter {part}\addcontentsline 
{toc}{part}{\thepart \hspace {1em}#1}\else \addcontentsline {toc}{part}{#1}\fi 
\markboth {}{}{\centering \interlinepenalty \@M \normalfont \ifnum \c@secnumdep
th >-2\relax \huge \bfseries \partname \nobreakspace \thepart \par \vskip 20\p@
 \fi \Huge \bfseries #2\par }\@endpart .
<insert>   \show\H@old@part

l.23 \show\@part

?
```

Good! There's nothing more to be looked for! Stop the interactive session, go back to the file and change `\@part` into `\H@old@part`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}}

\newcommand\insertepigraph{} % Insert an epigraph at the bottom of a part page
\newcommand\clearpartepigraph{\renewcommand\insertepigraph{}} % Clear the part epigraph
\newcommand\partepigraph[2]{\renewcommand{\insertepigraph}{\epigraph{#1}{#2}}} % Define the part epigraph

\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\H@old@part}
  {\@endpart}%
  {\vfill\insertepigraph\clearpartepigraph\@endpart}%
  {\PackageWarning{Patch}{Success}}
  {\PackageWarning{Patch}{Failure}}

\xpatchcmd{\H@old@part}
  {\markboth{}{}}%
  {\markboth{}{}\vskip 0.25\textheight}%
  {\PackageWarning{Patch}{Success}}
  {\PackageWarning{Patch}{Failure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\partepigraph{\footnotesize La notion de passoire est indépendante de la notion de trou, et réciproquement.\\ \vskip3mm The notion of a colander is independant of the notion of a hole, and reciprocally.}{Rouxel (Les Shadoks)\\ \textit{{\scriptsize mocking the non-intuitive principles of quantum mechanics.}}}

\part{Some part title}

\part{Some other part title}

\part{Again some other part title}

\chapter{Ciel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to have the patches in a personal package; in this case the original patching can be done there, provided you load this personal package before `hyperref`. Or, if you want “independent” code to be after package loading, just use a trick:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {\xpatchcmd{\H@old@part}}
  {\xpatchcmd{\@part}}
  {\@endpart}%
  {\vfill\insertepigraph\clearpartepigraph\@endpart}%
  {\PackageWarning{Patch}{Success}}
  {\PackageWarning{Patch}{Failure}}

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {\xpatchcmd{\H@old@part}}
  {\xpatchcmd{\@part}}
  {\markboth{}{}}%
  {\markboth{}{}\vskip 0.25\textheight}%
  {\PackageWarning{Patch}{Success}}
  {\PackageWarning{Patch}{Failure}}
\makeatother
```